# Find duplicate records based on a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with members and I need to find all members with the same name. How do I write it with SQL?

This is the table:

```
create table Members( 
  MemberID char(13), 
  Name varchar(20),
  primary key(MemberID) 
)engine=innodb;


insert into Members(MemberID, Namn) values(’111’, ’John’);
insert into Members(MemberID, Namn) values(’222’, ’John’);
insert into Members(MemberID, Namn) values(’333’, ’Ralph’);
insert into Members(MemberID, Namn) values(’444’, ’Tony’);
insert into Members(MemberID, Namn) values(’555’, ’Ben’);
```

What I need is to extract MemberID's for all members with the same name - which should return 111 and 222 in this example.

Comment: Edit your question and add sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: new  to sql do some researchings and such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ffdc7/1)

You can use this query to get your desired result :

```
select * from Members where Name in(
    select Name from Members
    group by Name having count(Name) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you .

```
SELECT
name, COUNT(*)
FROM
<Table Name>
GROUP BY
name
HAVING 
COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Close. you need to use that in a subquery and join that to the member table then you will get a members with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH members_1 AS
(
    SELECT UPPER (name) AS name1
    FROM   members 
)
SELECT x.name1,y.memberid FROM 
(
    SELECT name1
    FROM members_1
    GROUP BY name1 
    HAVING COUNT(name1) > 1
) x 
JOIN members y ON UPPER(x.name1) = UPPER(y.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  select memberid 
    from 
    (
    select count(*) count,group_concat(memberid) memberid,name 
    from members group by name
    ) membertable
    where membertable.count>1
```